# using libtdsodbc.so in a docker container

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql-server, docker, sqlalchemy

I am having a mssql server running in docker, I want to connect the server using sqlalchemy

For connecting, I am using this connection string,

```
engine = create_engine(
    'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s' % (
        urllib.parse.quote_plus(
            'DRIVER={/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so};SERVER=localhost;'
            'DATABASE=ap;UID=sa;PWD=admin@123;port=1433;'
            )), 
)
```

For this, I got this error,

> sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

Then, I figured that this file is missing. How to get `libtdsodbc.so` file

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

the docker mssql server is 2017,

in docker status, the port is shown as `0.0.0.0:1433->1433/tcp, :::1433->1433/tcp`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can install libtdsodbc.so using

```
apt update
apt install tdsodbc
```

although the Ubuntu 22.04 repo installs a rather old version, 1.3.6 (released 17 months ago), whereas the most recent stable release is currently 1.3.18 (released 7 weeks ago).

Also, SQLAlchemy is not tested with FreeTDS ODBC for the `mssql+pyodbc://` dialect, so you may be happier in the long run if you use Microsoft's ODBC driver for SQL Server as suggested in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76315916/2144390).

Answer (score 0):

You can install the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server on Linux by following the instructions here:

```
if ! [[ "18.04 20.04 22.04" == *"$(lsb_release -rs)"* ]];
then
    echo "Ubuntu $(lsb_release -rs) is not currently supported.";
    exit;
fi

sudo su
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -

curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/$(lsb_release -rs)/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

exit
sudo apt-get update
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql18
# optional: for bcp and sqlcmd
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y mssql-tools18
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools18/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
# optional: for unixODBC development headers
sudo apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev
```

[Install the Microsoft ODBC driver for SQL Server (Linux)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=ubuntu18-install%2Calpine17-install%2Cdebian8-install%2Credhat7-13-install%2Crhel7-offline)

Comment: I am using ubuntu 22.04.2, it is not supported, is there any other possible way, and i am using the mssql which is in docker container

Comment: It is supported.  The support matrix is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/system-requirements?view=sql-server-ver16